# Unable to play RTSP video in Qt media player demo

Tags: qt, directshow, gstreamer, rtsp, phonon

I was trying to develop a video management software for which I was evaluating Qt Phonon. The software would be built on windows platform and I understand that Phonon uses Directshow as windows backend and if it runs on Linux it uses GStreamer. Using Qt 4.7.4 on Linux which has a demo example of a video player using phonon I was successfully able to see video stream from panasonic IP camera (RTSP stream), however when I tried the same example on windows platform it does not work (returns error 0x800c0000d). What could be the problem?

Regards,

Saurabh Gandhi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x800c000d` is `INET_E_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL`, which in turn is "The specified protocol is unknown". DirectShow and Windows don't offer anything standard to support RTSP feeds, so the two together suggest that the IP camera feeds are not supported (at least without third party components).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I may say that Phonon sucks a lot. If you're not to attached to Phonon, use GStreamer withQt binding for it. You will get a lot more "cross platform" experience with it, as you're using same backend all the time so most of the media files works same way. As the GStreamer and it's [Qt bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/qt-gstreamer.html) are LGPL, you still may use it in closed source application.

Comment: that solution would not work for windows, right? Gstreamer does not support windows as far as my understanding goes...

Comment: I used gstreamer from OSSBuild project on windows without any problem. Everything worked fine